# onclick redirect to different url

Tags: javascript

I am creating a pulldown menu that pushes the user to a selected url. In the list i have several values that are set at 0 which i use for headers in the list. I have set them to 0 so they do nothing.

This works for the first one in the list which has a value of 0 but the others that do have a value of 0 still redirects the browser to a new website with the same domain and /0 at the end? What am i missing?

```
<select onchange="if (this.selectedIndex > 0) document.location.href=this.value;">
<option value="0" selected="selected">More...</option>
<option value="0">----- Locations  -----</option>
<option value="http://www.location1.com/">location1</option>
<option value="http://www.location2.com/">location2</option>
<option value="http://www.location3.com/">location3</option>
<option value="0">----- Other Locations  -----</option>
<option value="http://www.olocation1.com/">olocation1</option>
<option value="http://www.olocation2.com/">olocation2</option>
<option value="http://www.olocation3.com/">olocation3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `this.selectedIndex` refers to the first, second, or third item in the list. Not the VALUE of what was clicked. `this.value` is what you are after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change your code to:

```
<select onchange="if (this[this.selectedIndex].value !== '0') document.location.href=this.value;">
<option value="0" selected="selected">More...</option>
<option value="0">----- Locations  -----</option>
<option value="http://www.location1.com/">location1</option>
<option value="http://www.location2.com/">location2</option>
<option value="http://www.location3.com/">location3</option>
<option value="0">----- Other Locations  -----</option>
<option value="http://www.olocation1.com/">olocation1</option>
<option value="http://www.olocation2.com/">olocation2</option>
<option value="http://www.olocation3.com/">olocation3</option>
</select>​
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pratik136/kWHXX/

### Why?

Your code:

```
onchange="if (this.selectedIndex > 0) document.location.href=this.value;"
```

was checking for the `index` of the selected `option` in the list. Now because list indices start from `0`, you were getting expected results when the first (or 0<sup>th</sup> index) item was selected. But all other items passed the `selectedIndex > 0` test and got redirected.

using

```
onchange="if (this[this.selectedIndex].value !== '0') document.location.href=this.value;"
```

basically checks for the `value` of the selected `index`, and if the `value !== '0'`, it redirects to it.

Answer (score 3):

You're redirecting them to the url `0`, which it interprets as `/0`. You probably want to do a check to make sure that the value is not `"0"`, by using something like `this.value !== "0"`.